# Unable to SignIn with Apple in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

We're working on the Flutter application in which we need to give support of the Apple SignIn for both Android and iOS. Before few days it was working properly on both of the platforms. But since last few days, we found that it is working on the iOS as expected but on the Android, it started giving the error as following

***"Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared."***

Is there anyone who's facing the same issue? Please help with this.

Thanks.